# error running 'git fetch origin refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*' while working with @io_bazel_rules_docker

Tags: linux, git, docker, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build tensorflow from source in a docker container. To download some packages, I sat the docker proxy to https://127.0.0.1:8118 (which points to Tor vi privoxy). I excluded *.github.com from this proxy

After running:

```
bazel build --config=monolithic //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: error running 'git fetch origin refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*' while working with @io_bazel_rules_docker
```

I tried to set proxy for git too via:

```
git config --global http.proxy https://127.0.0.1:8118
```

with no success

Answer (score 0):

There was no need to exclude `github` from proxy.

Anyways setting `git` proxy can resolve the problem, however it should be `https` and not only `http` proxy.

```
git config --global https.proxy https://127.0.0.1:8118
```

If you run this command in the docker container, you must use `--network=host` option for the docker to recognize the localhost IP address. The `--net=host` option is used to make the programs inside the Docker container look like they are running on the host itself, from the perspective of the network.